# Functions that Tend To Non-Smooth Functions as Some Parameter Tends to Infinity

Tags: approximation, continuity, piecewise-continuity

I recently saw a post in which the query was about a function that tends to the Dirac delta function as a parameter in it tends to infinity. The function chosen was $${(1+\cos x)^n\over C}$$ as $n\to\infty$, with C being the integral of the given function from $-\pi$ to $+\pi$. The *specific* query of the post was infact to do with this normalisation constant. Another way of doing this would be with a parametrised *Gaussian* $$\sqrt\frac{\alpha}{\pi}\exp(-\alpha x^2)$$ as $\alpha\to\infty$.

Various other non smooth functions can be represented as limits of parametrised smooth functions as the parameter tends to infinity: |x| can be represented as $${1\over\alpha}\ln\cosh(\alpha x)$$ (or as $${1\over\alpha}\ln(2\cosh(\alpha x))$$ ... it doesn't really matter whether the 2 is there or not; the *sharp-cornered-sigmoid* function ( $$x\leq -1 ⇒y=-1 ,$$$$ -1<x<+1⇒y=x, \&$$$$x\geq 1⇒y=+1$$ by $$\frac{1}{\alpha}\left(\ln\left(1+\exp(\alpha(1+x))\right)-\ln\left(1+\exp(\alpha(1-x))\right)\right)-x .$$ or, equivalently

$$\frac{1}{\alpha}\ln\frac{1+\exp(\alpha(1+x))}{1+\exp(\alpha(1-x))}-x .$$

Does anyone know any other limits of parametrised smooth functions for representing either these or other non-smooth functions in this kind of way?

I have found these kinds of function handy in computer graphics; and also in the numerical solution of differential equation: if, say, a forcing function or boundary condition is a non-smooth function of which the being encoded raw into the solution algorithm would cause the propagation of artifacts, then a function such as one of these could be coded-in instead ... and it could even be *fine-tuned* such that the *sharpnesses* of it be as much as the algorithm can tolerate.

And plugging the one for $|x|$ into the one for the sharp cornered sigmoid, and turning the result upside-down, you could get a unit *tent* function with $$1-{1\over\alpha}\ln\frac{1+e^\alpha \cosh(\alpha x)}{e^\alpha+\cosh(\alpha x)} ,$$ which you might as well reduce to $$1-{1\over\alpha}\ln\frac{e^\alpha \cosh(\alpha x)}{e^\alpha+\cosh(\alpha x)} $$ or $$1+{1\over\alpha}\ln(e^{-\alpha}+\operatorname{sech}(\alpha x)) .$$

Comment: Sequence $f_n$ with $f_n(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\mathrm(atan)(nx)$ converges to a variant of Heaviside step function.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks - I see that: & you could get the Heavyside function itself with lim{α→∞}(1/2+(1/π)atn(αx))

Comment: Yes. About the first function you give, a simpler version is : $K\cos(x)^n$. See the answer of yves Daoust in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2293384 given for convergence towards a gauss function with a different normalization.

Comment: No doubt though the "1+" business is an expedient  for obviating negative values ... and also it results in a function that meets the x-axis tangentially in the 'wings'. The post is "Proving a sequence of functions is an aporoximation to the identity". I havent got the URL, as I'm using the 'app', & the URL is not displayed in it. But I'll check your link out & look at the counter reasons.

Comment: In fact, due to formula $1+\cos(2a)=2\cos(a)^2$, it amount to the same...

Comment: It says something like that in the post itself, now you jog my memory by mentioning it.

Comment: You surely mean this refernce : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3022167

Comment: That is indeed the one! It would be handy if I could get that serial number somehow using the app. Hang-on ... you showed me it in the firstplace, didn't you! Sometimes I can be just _so so_ dense!

Comment: Or ... no you didn't. Whatever ... I _do_ do things like that _anyway_ ... I've even answered my own questions & comments, forgetting they're mine! Not on here ... on other fora. Don't _think_ I've done that on here yet!

Comment: Just click on your square icon on the StackExchange upper taskbar, then select item "all actions"

Comment: I've had a look at that post: it's very interesting. Thankyou for showing me it ... my kind of thing. ¶ That business of the _taskbar_ - I don't think it's present on the app. The app, really, is in want of _very_ much improvement. I'll keep hacking at it though, as I would _very much like_ to be able to make these _cross-references_. ¶ As for that answering my own posts & comments unawares ... you'll be relieved to learn, I surmise, that I _nearly always_ strongly agree with myself!

Answer (score 1):

To get the heavyside step function, any unboundedly 'encelerated' sigmoid function can be used, with a little scaling & vertical displacement, such as $$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi}\operatorname{atn}(\alpha x)$$ or $$\frac{1}{2}(1+\operatorname{tanh}(\alpha x)) .$$ The function $\tanh$ has the *theoretical* advantage of being one that cleaves more closely to the limits $y=-1$ & $y=+1$; but on the other hand, it's worth keeping both of these in mind, as in a use of such as these *in practice* for the kind of thing I have given a use of them for, the greater 'slackness' of $\operatorname{atn}$ could actually be an advantage (in fact I *have found* that sometimes it *is*). Also in similar fashion a square pulse can be represented by $$\frac{1}{\pi}(\operatorname{atn}(\alpha (1-x))+\operatorname{atn}(\alpha (1+x)))$$ or by $$\frac{1}{2}(\operatorname{tanh}(\alpha (1-x))+\operatorname{tanh}(\alpha (1+x))) .$$